# How to create work sheets dynamically using XSLT?

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-2008, xslt

I want to create the worksheets dynamically based on dataset results (all data set results are same output format)returned by procedure.

```
XML :

<NewDataset>
<Table>
 <record>
 <id>1</id>
 <name>sdf</name>
<record>
<record>
<id>2</id>
 <name>sdfooop</name>
</record>
</Table>
<Table1>
<record>
 <id>1</id>
 <name>sdffff</name>
<record>
<record>
<id>2</id>
 <name>sdfwerwerwe</name>
</record>
</Table1>
```

In above example stored procedure returning 2 result sets Table,Table1.(This results set count may vary ).Please tell me how to dynamically create worksheets in same workbook using XSLT .

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/NewDataset">
    <Workbook>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'Table')]">
            <Worksheet>
                <xsl:for-each select="record">
                    <Row>
                        <xsl:for-each select="*">
                            <Cell>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </Cell>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Worksheet>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Workbook>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If suppose different formats of output returned by SP (Table,Table1 outputs are different).(Table3,Table4,Table5 ...etc outputs are same).Please don't make mistake ,new to XSLT..I learnt alot but confusion on this scenario.

Comment: I don't think it should make a difference, as long as each `TableN` has child 'record`elements. The cell element names do not play a role here.

Comment: thanks for your reply..in above code how can i give worksheet name dynamically,same name we can't give for all sheets(throwing error).

Comment: You could use `concat('Workseet', position())`.

Comment: thanks michael ,any way to give names for worksheets  instead position values..tried many ways like to read node element text and assigning it as worksheet name.But not able to achieve.please advice on this.

Comment: If you want to name your worksheets the same as the original "TableN" elements, then use the `name()` function to get the name.

Comment: In my case Worksheet is excel type ,given <ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"> .then can i give xsl functions in worksheet ? ex : <ss:worksheet ss:Name="concat('worksheet',name()) like this..