# How to apply for each loop on worksheet tag in XSLT?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, sql-server-2008, xslt

I want to apply for each loop before  work sheet tag in XSLT ..
I applied like the below ..

```
<xsl:for-each select="1to4">
<worksheet >
</worksheet>
</xsl>
```

above code getting error ...
I need to create the worksheets dynamically,because my procedure dataset results are varying ..

sample results returned by procedure :

```
XML :

<NewDataset>
<Table>
 <record>
 <id>1</id>
 <name>sdf</name>
<record>
<record>
<id>2</id>
 <name>sdfooop</name>
</record>
</Table>
<Table1>
<record>
 <id>1</id>
 <name>sdffff</name>
<record>
<record>
<id>2</id>
 <name>sdfwerwerwe</name>
</record>
</Table1>
</NewDataset>
```

Here , 2 dataset results(Table,Table1) are displaying ,some times more datasets are coming(Table,Table1,Table2..etc),So I want to loop the worksheets ..
please help me on this ..

thanks in advance

Comment: why the negative ???

Comment: probably because you haven't displayed any efforts and or attempts of code just posting XML is not good enough and this is not a code factory service.. also have you even tried a google search..?

Comment: yes i tried may ways to loop the sheets creations ,i am getting error on for-each loop..help me on this

Comment: "above code getting error" - what error is it "getting"?

Comment: how can anyone help you when we don't know the errors nor have you shown the code that you are using in regards to `foreach`

Comment: Do you actually just want a separate `worksheet` element for each `TableX` element under `NewDataset`? If so, perhaps you can just do `<xsl:for-each select="//NewDataset/*">` to select each table?

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="1to4">
<worksheet >
</worksheet>
</xsl>
```

has invalid syntax. The correct syntax is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 4">
<worksheet>
</worksheet>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that this requires an XSLT 2.0 processor. Judging by your other tags, you are probably using a Microsoft processor, which is XSLT 1.0 only.

---

Note also that none of this is necessary if - as it seems - you want to create a worksheet for each `TableN` element. I have shown how to do this in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38059521/3016153).

Comment: I changed my XSLT version to 2.o ,but not able to get..Is it mandatory to give worksheet name ?

Comment: "*I changed my XSLT version to 2.o*: That makes no difference. You need a processing engine that supports XSLT 2.0. If you don't have it, rewrite your code using a recursive template.

Comment: recursive template means : <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/>

      <xsl:if test="$count > 0">  is this correct?

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: can you tell me  <xsl:param name="count" select="1"/> <xsl:if test="$count > 0"> in this syntax what is test attribute..

Comment: Please don't ask an entirely new question in a comment.